# pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have a question regarding these 2 functions:
When `pthread_cond_signal` is called before `pthread_cond_wait`, where exactly does the signal end up? In some kind of queue and then waits until pthread_cond_wait is called ?

I didn't find an explanation regarding this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Condition variable signals are [edge events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966863/level-vs-edge-trigger-network-event-mechanisms).  That means, if you signal a CV when no one is waiting for it, the event is discarded.  This is spelled out in the [official spec for `pthread_cond_signal`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_signal.html):

> The pthread_cond_broadcast() and pthread_cond_signal() functions **shall have no effect** if there are no threads currently blocked on cond.

(emphasis mine)